# Not able to load chrome executable placed in resources in mac (works well in windows)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, eclipse-rcp, selenium-chromedriver

I have chrome driver executable in resources folder(both windows and mac executables). I am trying to open chrome driver by fetching relative path. Below I am attaching the sample code I used.

```
URL chromeDriverURL =
            Activator.getDefault().getBundle().getEntry("/resources/chromedriver");
File chromeDriver = null;
try {
      URL resolvedFileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(chromeDriverURL);
      URI resolvedURI = new URI(resolvedFileURL.getProtocol(), resolvedFileURL.getPath(), null);
      chromeDriver = new File(resolvedURI);
      /*chromeDriver =
                    new File(FileLocator.resolve(chromeDriverURL).toURI());*/
```

Below is the exception that is occurring:

```
exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /Users/SOME PATH/../../Desktop/SOMEPATH/resources/chromedriver
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:177)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:121)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:112)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:89)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:139)
```

Same code works in windows when I use "/resources/chromedriver.exe".

Any help would be apprecited.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the file is not executable - `File.canExecute` returns false. Try calling

```
chromeDriver.setExecutable(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try making it executable - chmod +x chromedriver